# MPAndroidChart - linechart realtime graph - remove x-values doesn't work

Tags: java, android, charts, linechart, mpandroidchart

I got a really annoying problem with my realtime graph. It works really pretty with `MpAndroidChart` library, but I guess I'm running out of memory. Because my realtime lineChart-graph become slower the longer it's running, until it get stuck. I didn't find any solution that works.

This is my linecharts screenshot

[image: this are my linecharts]
This is my code to enter values into charts,

`( test01 - test04 are possible solution from other posts, I tried )`

```
  private void addEntry(double[][] pts) {
//    System.out.println("#########   addEntry   #########");

if (mLineChartObj != null) {
  int anzLineChartObj = mLineChartObj.size();
//      System.out.println("#########   Anzahl LineChartObj: " + anzLineChartObj);

  for (int i = 0; i < anzLineChartObj; i++) {
    LineChartObject ob = mLineChartObj.get(i);
    LineData data = ob.lineChart.getData();

    if (data != null) {
      data.addXValue((ob.set).getEntryCount() + "");
      data.addEntry(new Entry((float) pts[ob.rootNodePos][0], (ob.set).getEntryCount()), 0);
//          data.addEntry(new Entry((float) (Math.random() * 9) + 0.45f, (ob.set).getEntryCount()), 0);
    }
//    °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
    if (data.getXValCount() > 1400) {

      System.out.println("X-ValueCount: " + ob.lineChart.getXValCount() + "   EntryValueCount: " + ob.set.getEntryCount() + "    ###############################");

//          Test 01 °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
//          for (int j = 0; j < 400; j++) {
//            data.removeXValue(0);
//            ob.set.removeEntry(0);
//          }

//          Test 02 °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
//          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
//            @Override
//            public void run() {
//              ob.lineChart.clearValues();
//            }
//          });

//          Test 03 °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
//          for (int j = 400; j > 0; j--) {
//            data.removeXValue(j + 999);
//            ob.set.removeEntry(j + 999);
//          }

//          Test 04 °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
//          data.removeXValue(0);
//          ob.set.removeEntry(0);

      System.out.println("X-ValueCount: " + ob.lineChart.getXValCount() + "   EntryValueCount: " + ob.set.getEntryCount() + "    ###############################");
    }
//    °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
//      notify chart data have changed
    ob.lineChart.notifyDataSetChanged();

//      limit number of visible entries
    float range = 200f;
//        ob.lineChart.setVisibleXRange(0f, range);
    ob.lineChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(range);
//      scroll the last entry
    ob.lineChart.moveViewToX(data.getXValCount() - (range + 1f));
  }
}
}
```

If I remove x-values from data or entries from set, several strange things happens. Sometimes the app gets crash, or the line of the charts begin to repeat itself, or sometimes I get more than one line per chart. I'm looking forward of a solution to remove old values from the chart.

EDIT 2:  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

The output of my linechart is like the following picture...It moves like a realtime graph, until xValues an amount of reach 1400, now my programm begins to remove entries and my linechart get stuck. After a while, the line begin to dissapear from the left side. At picture 1 it get stuck, at the next three pictures you can see how it dissapears.

[image]

Comment: Try calling `removeEntry(...)` before calling `removeXValue(...)`

Comment: Code occurance at "Test 04 °°°°°"... I tried your suggestion but it doesn't matter. Same result...

Answer (score 0):

I've been stuck with exactly the same problem today as I'm writing an app that visualizes sensor data. I just came up with the following makeshift solution that works for me:

```
    // (following code snippet is from an event listener)

    final ArrayList<Float> values = event.getValues();
    final LineData data = mChart.getData();
    // add data entry
    if (mIndex < MAX_PLOT_SIZE) {
        maxValue = 0f;
        data.addXValue("" + mIndex);
        for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
            final Float val = values.get(i);
            final LineDataSet set = data.getDataSetByIndex(i);
            set.addEntry(new Entry(val, mIndex));
        }
        mIndex++;
    } else {
        // shift values down
        for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
            final LineDataSet set = data.getDataSetByIndex(i);
            final List<Entry> yVals = set.getYVals();
            final int size = yVals.size();
            for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++) {
                yVals.get(j).setVal(yVals.get(j + 1).getVal());
            }
            // add new value
            final Float val = values.get(i);
            yVals.get(size - 1).setVal(val);
        }      
    }
```

It's admittedly a hack and there should be an easier way to do it, but at least it gets the job done. I guess you could try and adjust the xVal-Strings in the same manner ...